# How to achieve this navigation tile effect with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MehSt/2/).

when I hover mouse on a particular tile its text displays and on mouseout it hides. (this works fine).

when I click on a link residing inside a particular tile (gold colored), text for that tile displays permanently(this should hide when other link is clicked).

Now problem is that When I click on a link residing inside another tile, text for all other tiles should be hidden, but this is not happening. 
this is my code of jQuery.

```
// -- navigation tile click -- //           
$('.nav a').on("click",function(){                 
     $(this).addClass('selected');                          
});

// -- navigation tiles mouseover -- //      
$('.nav > div').on("mouseover",function(){  
    $(this).find('.abs').show();        
}).on("mouseout",function(){
    if(!$(this).find('a').hasClass('selected'))
    {
        $(this).find('.abs').hide();
    }
});
```

What is the better way to this? what is the better way to write jQuery for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think you want to achieve this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
     $('.nav').on("click",function(){               
          $(this).addClass('selected');                
          $(this).find('.abs').show();  
          $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
          $(this).siblings().find('.abs').hide();                          
     });


    // -- navigation tiles mouseover -- //      
     $('.nav').on("mouseover",function(){  
         $(this).find('.abs').show();        
     }).on("mouseout",function(){
         if(!$(this).hasClass('selected'))
           {
             $(this).find('.abs').hide();
           }
      });
});
```

Here is the latest JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MehSt/8/
Because of little complicated HTML structure, I have pointed at 'div', rather than on 'a' tag.

Comment: I have done some changes to this code. here is the latest Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/MehSt/10/

Comment: Yes, shorter and better - even  var _this = $(this); can be removed. :)

Comment: var _this = $(this); by doing this I am reducing repetitive call to  $(this).

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure that i understand... :)Is creating of that var as 'container' better for performance (probably?), or it can be done like this, too:  http://jsfiddle.net/MehSt/11/ ? What is difference? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is batter for performance. see this http://gregfranko.com/jquery-best-practices/#/23  and http://developers.zyncro.com/entries/21188877-Guidelines-Best-Practices

Comment: this one also http://gregfranko.com/jquery-best-practices/#/13 and new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MehSt/13/

Answer (score 6):

take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vilaskumkar/8Rsgu/)

```
$('.nav > div').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.abs').stop().animate({marginLeft:100});
    },function(){
    $(this).find('.abs').stop().animate({marginLeft:0});
});

$('.nav a').click(function(){
    $('.nav a').removeClass("active");
    $('.nav a').next("span").animate({marginLeft:0}).removeClass("absActive");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).next("span").addClass("absActive");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this first remove class from `.nav a` then add `selected` for a clicked element

```
$('.nav a').on("click",function(){ 
    $('.nav a').removeclass("selected")
    $(this).addClass('selected');                           
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MehSt/7/)

Comment: I tried this as well earlier before asking question here,  but using this none of the text displays permanently. It shows and hides on mouseover and mouseout respectively.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding as am assuming check out this below link
http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/MehSt/4/

**check the code here**

```
$('.nav a').on("click",function(){
    $('.abs').hide();
    $(this).next('span').show();
    $(this).addClass('selected');                           
});
```

Comment: After click on a link when you just hove mouse on another tile(do not click), then text for both the tile is displayed. when hover mouse on all the tile, text of all the style is displayed but don't hide.

Comment: please confirm me that am going right way? we can fix that problem am also faced it but am not fix it because am not sure that am correct. let me know